# SQL Delete Statement taking a long time to run (oracle)

Tags: performance, sql-delete

In a timesheet system, there is the charge tree where we enter projects for employees to add to the timesheet.   We are wanting to start cleaning this up on old projects that have ended, etc.

This is the statement, I have re-written it in many different ways but it always take a long time, even when there are no record to delete.

I am self taught so bear with me please, I am almost positive it has to do with the **concat(mo.bld_proj_id,'%') like ud2.udt02_name** portion

(here is an example of the two fields and how the data looks that I am trying to compare.
[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5Mh.png)

```
    DELETE FROM tc_0002.charge_branch_charge@etime ctree
WHERE ctree.charge_cd IN
            (SELECT ud2.udt02_id
             FROM tc_0002.udt02@etime ud2
             INNER JOIN deltek.mo_hdr mo
                ON concat(mo.bld_proj_id,'%') like ud2.udt02_name
            WHERE ud2.udt02_id=ctree.charge_cd
            AND mo.s_mo_status_cd in ('L','C') 
            AND mo.complt_dt <= SYSDATE -7
            OR mo.allow_timesheet_fl='N');
```

It deletes as is supposed to it just takes a really long time for the script to run even when there are no records to delete. (last time it ran almost 20 minutes).

Comment: Yes you're right, that expression is not sargable and is forcing a table/index scan. Imagine a row of a milion boxes and I asked you to find the boxes containing a certain item but forced you to have to examine and open every one.... that's what you're doing to your database engine.

Comment: Not looking for a solution, but just to be pointed in the right direction for research.  I want to understand what and why I am doing whatever I am doing when I make a change to it.   So if you have any functions or something that I could research to help me achieve what is needed.

The real issue is no two columns in both tables match exactly.